# Decreasing Counter

Tags: c#, wpf, counter

I am wondering how I can make a decreasing counter to replace a timer, as in the timer would start at 3, and decrease every second, until reaching zero, where it would preform an action. Any Help?

```
// Change Image from "Hut" to Mole \\
private void ChangeImage()
{
        Image newImage = HoleImage();
        molePopup = MoleImage();
        int numCol = Convert.ToInt32(NumberOfColumns);
        //Random Number - Col
        Random randomColumns = new Random();
        int ranCol = randomColumns.Next(1, numCol);
        //Random Number - Row
        Random randomRow = new Random();
        int ranRow = randomRow.Next(1, NumberofRows);
        string Moleimage = TUtils.GetIniFileString(Moleini, "ImagePath", "PictureFile", Root + "mole2.png");
        //Populate Grid with Mole at Random Times \\
        Grid.SetRow(molePopup, ranRow);
        Grid.SetColumn(molePopup, ranCol);
        grid_Main.Children.Add(molePopup);

        molePopup.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler((o, e) =>
        {
            MolePoints++;
            grid_Main.Children.Remove(molePopup);
        });
}
```

Comment: Save a variable that is increased every second, subtract this variable from the counter start value and if it is 0, perform your action? I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @xmashallax I'm sorry I am new to C#, if you can, can you gave me an example?

Comment: How does the code sample relate to the Timer?  And what's wrong with using a Timer?

Answer (score 0):

I may be unclear, but as long as you only have the one thread in the program (and nothing going on otherwise), you'd use something like this:

```
for(int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

doWhatever();
```

For each iteration of the loop, you "sleep" the thread 1000 milliseconds, or 1 second. To do this, you will need to include System.Threading with `using System.Threading`. If you're doing something in the background, use alternate methods instead of Sleep, since it locks the thread execution for the duration specified.

EDIT:

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) is the MSDN documentation for `Thread.Sleep()` method. Seems to be very similar to what you want to do, if I take your meaning correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried using the Sleep function, it did not work out to well.

Comment: It froze the entire program, for the time it was set, I also have a lot of other background processes running at the same time.

Comment: That's basically what Thread.Sleep() does. What exactly are you trying to do? Output a countdown timer as well?

Comment: And why can't you use a DispatcherTimer (as mentioned within a deleted answer)?

Comment: So, I am making a Whack a Mole game, and I need to be able to show the image of a mole, then put an image of a mole hole. The counter would say, "wait a few seconds, then put the mole hole there", but I can not use a dispatcher timer, because using the sleep function as a delay halted the progrsm to a complete stop.

Comment: Hm, would it be possible to do the sprite (assuming you're using XNA/MonoGame) movement in the same control structure (the for loop) immediately after the Thread.Sleep() call?

Comment: No, that would lag the entire program. (I am not using XNA/MonoGame), I will just add some of the code to the question. :)

Comment: Call this... idk, simplistic, but would it be possible to break that 1000 milliseconds up into blocks, then do things in between those blocks?

Ex:

`for(int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
{
    Thread.Sleep(250);
    MoveMole();
    Thread.Sleep(250);
    MakeHutAppear();
    Thread.Sleep(250);
    TheSameThingWeDoEveryNightPinky();
    Thread.Sleep(250);
    TryToTakeOverTheWorld();
}

doWhatever();`

Comment: Without putting `DoEvents()` in the loop there is no opportunity for the user interface to update.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx)
2. Set the interval property to 1000 (= 1 second)
3. Create a variable that represents your countdown timer
4. Create a tick event in which you check if your countdown variable is zero. If it is zero => stop timer and perform action. If not => decrease variable
5. Start the timer